# Javascript Validation Framework for Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone.js comes with model validation events, and I'm looking to integrate it with a lite validation framework.

I just started looking at http://happyjs.com/

any other recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is my favorite its well documented and used by many

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Backbone.Validations plugin](https://github.com/n-time/backbone.validations)

Answer (score 0):

There are some validations plugins for backbone but I don't like it, I ended up with this:

```
...
validate: (attrs) ->
  helper = @validationHelper attrs
  helper.check 'name', (v) -> "can't be blank" if _(v).isBlank()
  helper.check 'version', (v) -> "can't be blank" if _(v).isBlank()
  helper.check 'organization', (v) -> "can't be blank" if _(v).isBlank()
  helper.errors()
...
```

And here's the helper:

```
  _(Backbone.Model.prototype).extend
    validationHelper: (attrs) ->
      helper = 
        _errors: {}
        check: (name, validator) ->
          return unless attrs and (name of attrs)
          msg = validator attrs[name]
          (@_errors[name] ?= []).push msg if msg
          @
        errors: -> if _(@_errors).any() then @_errors else null
      return helper
```